# Cakephp 4.x Conditional $rules->isUnique(['email'] only works on add, not udate operations in buildRules

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Trying to implement conditional validation logic thru buildRules.  Logic works on add, but not on update operations.  I have verified that the rule returns true on update and false on add.

My Table Model:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\Error\Debugger;
use Cake\Log\Log;
```

```
   public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker {     
      $rules->add(function ($entity, $options) use($rules) {
         if ($entity->send_email == 'Y') {
            $rule = $rules->isUnique(['email'], 'The email should be unique for MailChimp'); // Works on add only
            return $rule($entity, $options); // Works on add only
         }
         return true;
      }, 'email');
      return $rules;
   }
```

I have tried

```
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker {
          $rules->add(function ($entity, $options) use($rules) {
             if ($entity->send_email == 'Y') {
                $rules->add($rules->isUnique(
                      ['email'], 'Error Message'
                ));
                return $rules;
             }
             return true;
          }, 'email');
          return $rules;
       }
```

Which on edit displays the flash message from the controller.
But on add displays no message and stays on the edit form.

Any suggestions or educational pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Sorry if this is not formatted correctly

**Update:**
| Name       | Type              | Collation           |
| ----------------| ----------------- | -------------------- |
| email           | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci |
| send_email | varchar(1)     | utf8_general_ci |

The purpose is to not let an update or add to the database if the email already exists and send_email flag == "Y"
It is valid for the email to exist multiple times as long as the send_email flag == "N"
The return true is is being generated in the from the unique check

```
    $rule = $rules->isUnique(['email'], 'The email should be unique for MailChimp'); // Works on add only
    Debugger::dump($rule($entity, $options));
    return $rule($entity, $options);
```

Comment: What data do you have in the database? And what row are you trying to update with what value? The row that is being updated is exempt from the unique check. Also have you checked from where `true` is being returned, ie is it the unique check, or your hardcoded `return true`?

Comment: I can only assume that the debug statement should tell me that this is where you capture both cases!? The schema is not really relevant, but the actual data! It's impossible to tell whether the result you are getting is legitimate, without knowing what the existing data, the data you trying to edit, and the new data looks like.

Comment: Thank you ndm.  The existing data in the table would be a duplicate e-mail with the send_email column set to "N"  What I am trying to achieve is only one combination of an email and send_email set to "Y".  Could have multiple duplicate emails as long as each record's send_email is set to "N".   I am new to this.  Am approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Editing timed out as I was trying to clarify.  You stated that the row being edited is exempt from the unique check. Any way around this?  On edit I am changing an existing record with a duplicate email and the send_email was set to "N".  Want I don't want the user to be able to do is leave the email address alone (duplicate) and change the send_email flag to "Y",  which would cause a duplicated combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then it sounds like simply including the `send_email` field in the rule should do what you're looking for, ie:

```php
if ($entity->send_email === 'Y') {
    $rule = $rules->isUnique(
        ['email', 'send_email'],
        'The email should be unique for MailChimp'
    );

    return $rule($entity, $options);
}

return true;
```

That way the lookup conditions will be like this:

```sql
WHERE email = 'unchanged@email' AND send_email = 'Y' ...
```

and thus the rule should fail if there already is an existing record with that `email` and `send_email` combination. The record you're editing will still be exempt, but that wouldn't be a problem, as it only matters what other records with that data may already exist.

Comment: That works.  My problem is that the program needs to accept my multiple duplicate email address where the send_email = 'N'.  I hacked together another approach which I will post as a possible answer.  I am learning Cakephp, so thank you very much for your input!

Comment: @smoeckel Why do you need something else when this one works? The rule returns `true` when `$entity->send_email` isn't `Y`, so your case of allowed duplicates should be covered?